# How Search filter javascript with get data from local Storage and parse DOM

Tags: javascript, html, dom, local-storage, web-storage

Please How to get data from local storage and parse DOM with the source code below :

```js
const forms = document.forms;
const searchBar = forms['searchBook'].querySelector('input');
searchBar.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
  const term = e.target.value.toLowerCase();
  const txt = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("TODO_APPS"));
  const books = document.querySelectorAll(".book_item");
  Array.from(books).forEach((book) => {
    const titlee = book.firstElementChild.textContent;
    if (titlee.toLowerCase().indexOf(e.target.value) != -1) {
      book.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
      book.style.display = 'none';
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: What is not working for you?

Comment: I can't do the search filter because the data is stored in localstorage and I don't know how to get data from local storage and parse json

Comment: please help me.. thank you

Comment: You are getting the data in the txt variable. I do not see you using that anywhere in the code. Try that and also add more info in your question.